# Entrar no site já com os bonequinhos

Tags: javascript, html

Olá

Estou com um pequeno problema que não sei resolver sozinho, basicamente quando entro no site aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E eu queria entrar no Site já com estes bonequinhos:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que os bonecos são gerados através de um script que estão ligados aos botões e eu queria entrar no site já com os bonecos sem que o select perca a função de reduzir o seu numero (numero dos bonecos) através das opções seleccionadas.

**Codigo:**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">

const urlIcon = 'https://1001freedownloads.s3.amazonaws.com/vector/thumb/74889/1367934593.png';
const imagem = `<img src="${urlIcon}" />`;

var json = [{
        "Nome": "Lucia Rodrigues",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Faro",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 46,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Vera Silva",
        "Idade": 30,
        "Distrito": "Setúbal",
        "Faixa Etaria": "26-35",
        "Faixa": "faixaC",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Maria Eufrázia",
        "Idade": 83,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Luzia Rosado",
        "Idade": 80,
        "Distrito": "Évora",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernanda",
        "Idade": 70,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Nome Desconhecido",
        "Idade": 48,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Marina Mendes",
        "Idade": 25,
        "Distrito": "Viseu",
        "Faixa Etaria": "18-25",
        "Faixa": "faixaB",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Helena Cabrita",
        "Idade": 60,
        "Distrito": "Madeira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Lana",
        "Idade": 2,
        "Distrito": "Madeira",
        "Faixa Etaria": "0-17",
        "Faixa": "faixaA",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Fernando Cruz",
        "Idade": 60,
        "Distrito": "Porto",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Masc",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Maria Silva",
        "Idade": 53,
        "Distrito": "Açores",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Sim"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Ana Paula",
        "Idade": 40,
        "Distrito": "Braga",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "Heila Lopes",
        "Idade": 44,
        "Distrito": "Lisboa",
        "Faixa Etaria": "36 ou mais",
        "Faixa": "faixaD",
        "Sexo": "Fem",
        "RecursoArma": "Não"
    }
    ]
    
    $(document).on("click", "#btnBuscar", function() {
  var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });

  console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
  const imagens = Array.from({
    length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
  }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
  $('#images').html(imagens);
});

$(document).on("click", "#btnLimpar", function() {
  $('#selectsfiltro').each (function(){
    this.reset();
  });

  var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });

  const imagens = Array.from({
    length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
  }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
  $('#images').html(imagens);
});

    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="selectsfiltro">
    <h6>Faixa Etaria:</h6>
    <select id="FaixaEtaria" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">0-17</option>
        <option value="2">18-25</option>
        <option value="3">26-35</option>
        <option value="4">36 ou mais</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <h6>Sexo:</h6>
    <select id="Sexo" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="5">Masc</option>
        <option value="6">Fem</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Recurso a arma:</h6>
    <select id="RecursoArma" class="custom-select">
        <option></option>
        <option value="7">Sim</option>
        <option value="8">Não</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h6>Localidade:</h6>
    <select id="Distrito" class="custom-select">
        <option ></option>
        <option value="9">Viana do Castelo</option>
        <option value="10">Vila Real</option>
        <option value="11">Bragança</option>
        <option value="12">Braga</option>
        <option value="13">Porto</option>
        <option value="14">Aveiro</option>
        <option value="15">Viseu</option>
        <option value="16">Guarda</option>
        <option value="17">Coimbra</option>
        <option value="18">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option value="19">Leiria</option>
        <option value="20">Lisboa</option>
        <option value="21">Santarém</option>
        <option value="22">Portalegre</option>
        <option value="23">Évora</option>
        <option value="24">Setúbal</option>
        <option value="25">Beja</option>
        <option value="26">Faro</option>
        <option value="27">Açores</option>
        <option value="28">Madeira</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>
<br/>

    <button id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Filtrar</button>
    <button type="reset" id="btnLimpar" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Limpar Filtro</button>
```

Ps: troquei os bonecos dentro deste codigo pois se deixa-se os outros o site não os iria encontrar e ia dar erro na imagem.

Comment: Pq vc já não inicia com alguma opção do Select já selecionada tipo `<option selected value="2">18-25</option>` aqui pode ter algu que te interesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=selected

Comment: @hugocsl pois se deixar algum dos selects com a função selected o meu script assim me como se fosse um dos filtros e interfere no resultado depois ao filtrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente é executar a função do Search assim que carregar, invés de aguardar o clique:

```
  showPeople();

  function showPeople() {

    var filtroFaixaEtaria = $("#FaixaEtaria option:selected").text();
  var filtroSexo = $("#Sexo option:selected").text();
  var filtroRecursoArma = $("#RecursoArma option:selected").text();
  var filtroDistrito = $("#Distrito option:selected").text();

  var arrayResultados = json.filter(function(item) {
    var criteria = true;

    if (filtroFaixaEtaria != null && filtroFaixaEtaria != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Faixa Etaria"] == filtroFaixaEtaria;
    if (filtroSexo != null && filtroSexo != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Sexo"] == filtroSexo;
    if (filtroRecursoArma != null && filtroRecursoArma != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["RecursoArma"] == filtroRecursoArma;
    if (filtroDistrito != null && filtroDistrito != "")
      criteria = criteria && item["Distrito"] == filtroDistrito;

    return criteria;

  });

  console.log("Foram encontrados " + arrayResultados.length + " elementos de acordo com a busca");
  const imagens = Array.from({
    length: Number(arrayResultados.length)
  }).reduce((html) => html + imagem, '');
  $('#images').html(imagens);
  }
```

Comment: a consola do visual studio code encontra 3 erros no seu codigo eu consegui resolver dois que era fechar um } mas falta um que tem alguma coisa a ver com uma virgula.

Comment: Esqueça, consegui resolver irei editar a sua resposta e marcar como correta! obg